# Other computers think my program is a virus

Tags: visual-studio, exe

I created a program in visual studio (winForm, C#),
I even built a release version, but when I tried running the program in a different computer than my own, the antivirus popped up and said there may be a risk in running this program

My program is a rubik's cube solver for anyone wondering

How can I make my program be trusted by other computers?

Comment: Maybe your program behaves like a virus? Why don't you tell us a bit more about what your program does?

Comment: What you have to do is *sign* the application

Comment: If you are using version control (maybe git?), you should search for moment where your program was NOT being detected. Revert to that moment and step by step add changes to test which place is cousing problem (hitig AV).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Aside from the fair chance that a virus on your computer actually infects the executables you share:

Not at all, since your program *is* unknown to the receiver, and it *is* a risk executing it. So, that warning is correct, and should be heeded.

You might do such things as signing your executable, but that will only certify that it's *your* program, and not that it's *harmless*.